# how to embed a java applet to silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, applet

I am working on a project where i have to embed a java applet (which contains rtsp streaming) into a silverlight application.
i am new to silverlight.
any idea how to work with that?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to google first, then try, then ask. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried all things but couldn't find the answer so i asked it over here.
if you have an answer please help me out.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible. You have to embed an applet into an html page (with specific tags like `<applet>` or `<object>`). It would be like asking how to embed an applet into a flash application or embed silverlight into an applet. Those are competing technologies with a similiar goal on bringing dynamic content to the enduser.

So what you can do is having a web page with both technologies - some silverlight content and an applet which both gets executed when the page is loaded in the browser...

I mean theoretically you could implement an html page generator in silverlight which generates an html page with an applet in it - but this is complex and I don't see the benefit currently...

Comment: I did it with .net
1. Create a simple Java Applet.
2. Create a default web application.
3. Copy the Applet1.class file to the web application folder.
4. Add a default user control to the web application.
5. Add the following HTML code in the user control.
<APPLET height="200" width="320" code="Applet1.class" name="Applet1"
VIEWASTEXT>
<PARAM NAME="foreground" VALUE="FFFFFF">
<PARAM NAME="background" VALUE="008080">
<PARAM NAME="label" VALUE="This string was passed from the HTML host.">
</APPLET>
6. Build and run the web application.

But my end goal is different.
anyways Thanks, :)